# Equivalent to tokenizer() in Transformers 2.5.0?

Tags: pytorch, tokenize, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to convert the following code to work with Transformers 2.5.0. As written, it works in version 4.18.0, but not 2.5.0.

```
# Converting pretrained BERT classification model to regression model
# i.e. extracting base model and swapping out heads

from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel, BertConfig, BertForMaskedLM, BertForSequenceClassification, AutoConfig, AutoModelForTokenClassification
import torch
import numpy as np

old_model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("textattack/bert-base-uncased-yelp-polarity")
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels=1) 
model.bert = old_model.bert

# Ensure that model parameters are equivalent except for classifier head layer
for param_name in model.state_dict():
    if 'classifier' not in param_name:
        sub_param, full_param = model.state_dict()[param_name], old_model.state_dict()[param_name] # type: torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor
        assert (sub_param.cpu().numpy() == full_param.cpu().numpy()).all(), param_name


tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("textattack/bert-base-uncased-yelp-polarity")
inputs = tokenizer("Hello, my dog is cute", return_tensors="pt")

with torch.no_grad():
    logits = model(**inputs).logits

output_value = np.array(logits)[0][0]
print(output_value)
```

tokenizer is not callable with transformers 2.5.0, resulting the following:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d83f0d613f4b> in <module>
     19 
     20 
---> 21 inputs = tokenizer("Hello, my dog is cute", return_tensors="pt")
     22 
     23 with torch.no_grad():

TypeError: 'BertTokenizer' object is not callable
```

However, attempting to replace tokenizer() with tokenizer.tokenize() results in the following:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1d431131eb87> in <module>
     21 
     22 with torch.no_grad():
---> 23     logits = model(**inputs).logits
     24 
     25 output_value = np.array(logits)[0][0]

TypeError: BertForSequenceClassification object argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

### Solution

Using tokenizer.encode_plus() as suggested by @cronoik:

```
tokenized = tokenizer.encode_plus("Hello, my dog is cute", return_tensors="pt")

with torch.no_grad():
    logits = model(**tokenized)

output_value = np.array(logits)[0]
print(output_value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly their documentation for the old versions is broken, but you can use encode_plus as shown in the following (he oldest available documentation of encode_plus is from [2.10.0](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.10.0/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.encode_plus)):

```py
import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizer


t = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("textattack/bert-base-uncased-yelp-polarity")
tokenized = t.encode_plus("Hello, my dog is cute", return_tensors='pt')
print(tokenized)
```

Output:

```
{'input_ids': tensor([[  101,  7592,  1010,  2026,  3899,  2003, 10140,   102]]), 
'token_type_ids': tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), 
'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])}
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks reasonable. Do you know how I can then feed "tokenized" into the model? "model(**tokenized)" results in "ValueError: Wrong shape for input_ids (shape torch.Size([8])) or attention_mask (shape torch.Size([8]))"

Comment: @galactic_tok sorry, my fault. I forgot to turn it into a batch.

Comment: All good! I figured it out. I used: 

'tokenized = tokenizer.encode_plus("Hello, my dog is cute", return_tensors="pt")

with torch.no_grad():
    logits = model(**tokenized)
    
output_value = np.array(logits)[0]
print(output_value)'